# "Proof" that time-reversal symmetry is impossible

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

I know the proof goes wrong. Where does it go wrong?

I obviously took inspiration from parity reversal. Parity reversal takes $X$ to $-X$ and consequently $P$ to $-P$. If the transformation leaves $H$ unchanged, then there's parity reversal symmetry in the problem.

Similarly, take the basis that is the Fourier transform of the $H$ basis (just like how $X$ basis is the Fourier transform of the $P$ basis). Let the Hermitian operator corresponding to this basis be $T$. So time-reversal takes $T$ to $-T$ and consequently $H$ to $-H$.

So, $H$ can never unchanged under this transformation because it takes $H$ to $-H$. The only way $H=-H$ if $H$ is the zero operator. $H$ doesn't remain unchanged implies there is no time reversal symmetry.

Comment: Time reversal takes $H(t)$ to $H(-t)$

Comment: Time-reversal is implemented by an anti-unitary, anti-linear operator so you need to be very careful about factors of $i$. It takes $i H \to - i H$ but since it is anti-unitary it also takes $i \to - i$. Put together, it implies that it takes $H \to H$ so it is a symmetry.